# New CentOS 7 install (Google Compute), can't add VirtualHost entries to /etc/httpd/conf.d/

Tags: virtualhost, httpd, google-compute-engine

I just did a base install and Apache 2.4 starts up just fine. I'm migrating from an old server which runs Apache 2.2.

When I put a file into `/etc/httpd/conf.d` that contains a `VirtualHost` definition and restart the server it crashes on startup. This VirtualHost definition is one I use from my previous server.

```
# systemctl restart httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
# systemctl -l status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-01-22 03:03:35 UTC; 10s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 20621 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 20620 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 20620 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 22 03:03:35 production-frontend-0 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 22 03:03:35 production-frontend-0 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 22 03:03:35 production-frontend-0 kill[20621]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jan 22 03:03:35 production-frontend-0 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 22 03:03:35 production-frontend-0 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 22 03:03:35 production-frontend-0 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jan 22 03:03:35 production-frontend-0 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
#
```

Here is the contents of the conf file (with the domain name changed):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    <Directory /home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI Includes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/html
    CustomLog /home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/logs/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/logs/error.log
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/cgi

    RewriteEngine on

    # Does the file exist?
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain.otherdomain.com [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I've checked the file syntax:

```
# httpd -t
Syntax OK
#
```

If I remove the file and restart, then Apache starts up just fine. I've made sure that the permissions on my files match up with the existing conf files:

```
# ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2926 Nov 14 18:04 autoindex.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  366 Nov 14 18:05 README
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1252 Nov 14 16:53 userdir.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  674 Jan 22 03:03 vhost.mydomain.com.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  824 Nov 14 16:53 welcome.conf
#
```

Did something change in Apache 2.4 that is conflicting with my VirtualHost definition?

Are there some kind of security measures in place in a standard Google Compute instance that is rejecting my configuration?

Is there some configuration option that I tweaked years ago on my old server and I've just forgotten that I need to tweak on my Google Compute instance? :)

EDIT:

Found this in the error log:

```
Permission denied: AH00649: could not open transfer log file /home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/logs/access.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I checked `httpd.conf` and it says the server runs as User:Group `apache:apache`. So I did the following to ensure apache had permission to write those log files:

```
chgrp -R apache /home/kenny/domains
chmod g+w /home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/logs
```

I still get the error. I even tried:

```
touch /home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/logs/access.log
chown kenny:apache /home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/logs/access.log
chmod g+w /home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/logs/access.log
```

Still giving me the error. I ensured that the ancestor path is executable to apache as well.

```
/home/kenny is owned by kenny:kenny and is 755
/home/kenny/domains is owned by kenny:apache and is 755
/home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com is owned by kenny:apache and is 755
/home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/logs is owned by kenny:apache and is 775
/home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/logs/access.log is owned by kenny:apache and is 664
```

Contents of the audit.log:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1485115416.525:2112): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=25759 comm="httpd" path="/home/kenny/domains/mydomain.com/logs/access.log" dev="sda1" ino=36516072 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1485115416.525:2112): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f6620cd15a8 a1=80441 a2=1b6 a3=ffffff00 items=0 ppid=1 pid=25759 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1485115416.567:2113): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=httpd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed
```

'

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: I commented out all of the lines in the VirtualHost directive and then have been uncommenting them and restarting to see where it breaks. When I introduced the `DocumentRoot` directive, it still started but I received this in the error log: `AH01630: client denied by server configuration` with the DocRoot. It still started though. When I enabled the `CustomLog` line, I saw a `permission denied` error in the log. I know how to go about fixing that one, but not the error about the DocumentRoot.

Comment: Hmm. You should also check the audit log.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the audit log. Where is that usually kept? Is that an apache log?

Comment: I think I found it and I've edited my post to include the output when I tried to start apache. I don't know how to decode the contents of an audit log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running CentOS 7, which has SELinux enabled by default.

When you try to start Apache, it tries to load files in a user's home directory, which isn't permitted by default.

You can allow Apache to *read* files in users' home directories by setting the appropriate boolean, `httpd_read_user_content`. It would be a better idea to relocate the web content to somewhere more appropriate, such as under `/srv/www` or `/var/www`.

However, there is no SELinux boolean to allow the web server to *write* to user home directories, which of course is inherently dangerous. You really should move the log files elsewhere. The standard location is `/var/log/httpd`. If users need to be able to read them, you can set permissions for them to do so.

Comment: Ah, SELinux is a new thing for me. I guess I'll need to do some reading. How do I set the `httpd_read_user_content` boolean? I have several users who aren't technically minded and need to be able to login and access their web files in a very simple fashion. If I move all of the web dirs to /var/www/<username>/, chown them to the user, and create a symlink in the user's dir, would that satisfy apache while keeping my easy structure for users?

Comment: `setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1`. See the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/index.html). And yes, that directory structure would be fine.

Comment: I haven't been able to get the /var/www arrangement working yet, I'm still getting some permissions errors that I need to work out, but I think your answer has solved my initial problem so I'm going to accept it and then probably post another question with my current, more specific, issue. Thanks!